# How are you going to stop scammers?

Tags: private-key, seed-phrase, scamming-and-phishing

I was the victim of a scammer today, they were asking for ADA and I lose all my savings. If a scammer gets 500k ADA that in the future for sure will become billions. Is there any chance it will finance terrorism?

Organise crime becomes more sophisticated through time. is there any strategy to stop or remediate these sorts of events?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this scam has been working since last year, https://cardanocompany.com/    It has videos in YouTube that redirect to web site, some of the videos have over a hundredth thousand likes… and hasn’t been shutdown by YouTube

Answer (score 7):

### About scamming and phishing

Fraudsters have always existed and will continue to exist. In the future, there will probably be network-based mechanisms to protect yourself against fraudsters, but so far the crypto industry is too young.

Currently, the police are reluctant to investigate cases of crypto fraud. The police show zeal only if the case is egregious.

### How to protect your assets

**Here are some tips for those who new to cryptocurrency.**

1. Use only official or time-tested wallets. Triple check if the software wallet you downloaded doesn't belong to scammers.
2. Use 24-word seed phrase for backup and strong password for encryption.
3. Never reveal your private key to anyone. Store your seed phrase or private key in a secure and hard-to-reach place.
4. For day-to-day small payments use devices like ***[Tangem crypto-note](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-tangem-wallet-or-nfc-powered-hardware-cryptobill-aeb3dcacafb)***.
5. Avoid phishing sites. Do not store large amounts of cryptocurrency on a computer connected to the Web.
6. Do not trust those who give away free ADA via faucet or any promotions. IOHK never gives away ADA for free.
7. Do not store your assets on a cryptoexchange account.
8. Be wise!

And here are ***[Cybersecurity guidelines for Cardano users.](https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/900005141163)***

Answer (score 2):

There are many algorithms which can be used to search trees for transaction patterns but at the end of the day, people can really only do what they can do now. Call local law enforcement. Cardano in not a privacy coin so ensure you provide the transaction info to them and their success would probably be pretty good... eventually. Vigilantism rarely ends well.