# How can I derive an address from a private key?

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, address, private-key

Checking the [official documentation from cardano-wallet](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/postWallet) I can see that there are options to get wallets from mnemonics and extended public keys, but not private keys.

Even [public libs](https://github.com/vacuumlabs/cardano-crypto.js/blob/develop/test/index.js) don't have that option. And as far as I know it's not possible to restore a wallet from a private key in Daedalus or Yoroi.

It's a somewhat simple functionality that I can't find any info about!

Answer (score 6):

A robust way to do that is to use ***cardano-wallet CLI***.

First of all, run ***cardano-wallet serve*** and ***cardano-node***.

### Root Key

The command that helps us writing a ***root private key*** into a file should look like this:

```
cardano-wallet recovery-phrase generate --size 18 \ 
    | cardano-wallet key from-recovery-phrase Shelley > secretKey.prv
```

It results in private key creation that might look like this:

```
root_xsk1vrv54w0rpg6j9qz54ed48hjf99k0qt7p4wu5l3y55tlpk8684dphx6a8xw82u3vsgwcv6n8mdxwczhfhusy22eknmdpjn9lnyram0alqaa7mwjx4rg0eyh3ckv0el34j5vswquzhvrpaze6ju6s623fs4ylx346v
```

### Derivation Path

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account_index' / role / address_index
```

If you tap a 20th receiving address in Daedalus wallet you'll see the following path:

```
m / 1852H / 1815H / 0H / 0 / 19
```

where `1852` is a hardened Shelley-era address type, and `1815` is hardened ADA's index.

### Account Keys

According to this scheme let's create ***account private key*** and ***account public key***:

```
cat secretKey.prv \
    | cardano-wallet key child 1852H/1815H/0H \
    | tee account.prv \
    | cardano-wallet key public --with-chain-code > account.pub
```

These results are:

```
acct_xsk10ra048lvz7le0y5pkmqmceuf492u64nv8edk9qsh3036jtz84dp3xqns35edmhag0nke3xmhm87368v8mtr5d2ryd3ucjgg6e5vjf7r8eu4ejhpyax2us59c73pt7sduvddy934k8p925xxsqvc2hh8nnug24fq6
```

...

```
acct_xvk1fpqtkwf8yy5rn3f79a4vr4fpd9rxxfheursjzqw8kgj0qf3q98ux0netn9wzf6v4epgt3azzhaqmcc66gtrtvwz24gvdqqes40w088c36lqsu
```

### Create a wallet

```
cardano-wallet wallet create from-public-key < 128-bit hash of acct pub key >
```

### Additional reading

If you need more details on Cardano CLI, please read my Medium stories:

- [**Cardano 911 — Wallet Command Line Interface (Part One)**](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-one-ad0ee5ac8509)
- [**Cardano 911 — Wallet Command Line Interface (Part Two)**](https://medium.com/@arkit/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-two-982a096c50e2)

Comment: That's for sure helpful. So I'd just start from the second step since I already have the private key. However, the question was geared towards achieving the same result programmatically, without the necessity of running a node or bash commands.

Comment: It entirely depends on the framework for the language in which you are developing. Many frameworks are in development at the moment. I personally use Swift – there are no any Cardano libs for Swift, except this one: https://thecardanofund.com/product/cardano-swift-sdk/