# Cardano Wallet - Using existing wallet and/or address generated from cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet

I'm kinda new in blockchain / crypto world (also Cardano world) and still learning things around.

Already setup cardano-node with cardano-wallets properly, both working good with testnet, by following this [guide as a starter path](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet).

All good and I understand bit-by-bit. BUT, when I reach [this part](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet#creating-a-wallet), which the second part, where it use `cardano-wallets`, I got some questions.

1. Is it possible if we use previously created wallet and address, `.skey`, `.vkey` and `.addr`, that being created from `cardano-cli` on `cardano-wallet`?

> [image]

2. If it's possible, how we can do that? I tried to check around the docs, but seems none mentioning it. As far as I check on forum, [this discussion is the closest](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/how-can-i-derive-an-address-from-a-private-key?rq=1) and [this one](https://medium.com/geekculture/cardano-911-wallet-command-line-interface-part-one-ad0ee5ac8509). But, I'm still not really understand it. Is there any documentation or link about it?

3. From No.2 above, is that link is the one that I want to achieve? since, when I read thoroughly, seems it's not the guide I'm looking for

---

Thanks for your time! :)