# How to find a cardano wallet's 'account public key'?

Tags: wallet

cardano-wallet has a method to create a new wallet:

cardano-wallet wallet create from-public-key WALLET_NAME ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY

If I use the public key I get:

Invalid account public key: expecting a hex-encoded value that is 64 bytes in length.

How can I find/derive this hex encoded 64 byte 'account public key'?

The only documentation I can find that mentions how to get the 'account public key' is this:

https://bump.sh/doc/cardano-wallet-diff#operation-getaccountkey

But this is using an API.
Surely I can find it using the cli ?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/how-can-i-derive-an-address-from-a-private-key